# Adaptor for Garmin Edge 530 out-front mount to a Go Pro

Tags: garmin

I am using the Garmin out-front mount for my Edge 530 and I am looking for an adapter that ables me to mount my Go Pro underneath the out-front mount. Does anyone know any method? Hacks?

P.s: I know K-Edge is making mounts but first I'd like to make sure there are no methods to use my original Garmin for this.

Also, found that Edge 530 mount is different that Garmin out-front mount you can buy on Garmin's website. The latter has four screw thread and as you can see mine doesn't.

[image: Out-front Garmin Edge 530 Mount]

Comment: Hi Amir, in light of your comment below, you could [edit] your question to include more details about what you've tried already, maybe show photos of why it's not working out?

Comment: Remember, the lower the camera the less it can see.  From a vision perspective, its ideal up high on the helmet, though this is questionable for safety and impaired helmet performance.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can get screw in adapters for Go Pros that thread into existing out front mounts from below. So if your out-front mount has metal screw threads already present, check underneath and see if you can get an adapter that will fit below to hold the Go Pro.

Otherwise, no hack can hold the weight of a Go Pro wobbling on a cantilever and given the cost of buying a new dedicated mount vs the cost of replacing a broken Go Pro, the only thing to do is get a proper mount. If you can afford to replace broken cameras you can afford to buy the proper mount in the first place ;)

Comment: Found this on AliExpress: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32873402573.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.60747a72Iz2wSY&algo_pvid=95f838c6-fb49-4bec-9a69-707fe3a88aeb&algo_expid=95f838c6-fb49-4bec-9a69-707fe3a88aeb-2&btsid=0ab6d69515860329715014432e298b&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: Concur - the gopro is not light, and it will pick up significant vibration when out on the end of an arm.  Example images in    https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36310/how-to-reduce-vibrations-to-handlebars-on-aluminium-road-bike

Comment: There is a wide aftermarket choice of mounts for GPS and action camera, even some made from metal on CNC machines.

Comment: @Criggie, interesting post. I myself have been trying many different mounts and found that Roll Bar Mount to be working the best. Also, forget about taking videos at night with these! I am gonna give a final try with the Garmin Combo and chances are I'll get back to the old mount or chest mounts.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a 3D printer, there are a ton of print files you can download at places like thingiverse.com. You might have to modify them a bit, but they are out there. Note you would need to print in something better than PLA to make this mount, say PETG or Nylon. See:

[Thingiverse GoPro Mounts](https://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=gopro%20camera%20mount&type=things&sort=relevant)